Anchor error while running test
pub struct InitUser<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [CONFIG_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_bytes(), authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub config_account: Box<Account<'info, ConfigAccount>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [USER_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_bytes(), authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + size_of::<UserAccount>()
    )]
    pub user_account: Box<Account<'info, UserAccount>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
const [configPda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("config"), deployKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
    
    const [userPda] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("user"), userKeypair.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    const userObj = {
      avatar: "avatar",
      name: "strong"
    }
    await program.methods.initUser(null, userObj.name).accounts({
      configAccount: configPda,
      userAccount: userPda,
      authority: userKeypair.publicKey,
      systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId
    }).signers([userKeypair]).rpc();

    const userAccount = await program.account.userAccount.fetch(userPda);
    console.log("User Account Before: ", userAccount);



AnchorError caused by account: config_account. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.

How can this error be resolved?

Your program uses authority.key() as a seed for both pdas
However, when you derive the pdas, you use deployKeypair.publicKey for one and userKeypair.publicKey for the second one.
Try using userKeypair.publicKey for both.

Thanks, i changed [CONFIG_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_bytes(), authority.key().as_ref()] to  [CONFIG_ACCOUNT_SEED.as_bytes(), config_account.authority.key().as_ref()] after looking at your answer.
